# Using variables as OFFSET in SELECT statments inside mysql's stored functions

Tags: mysql, stored-functions

I'm quite new to subject of writting stored function for mySQL database, hence i'm not sure if what i'm trying to do here is possible at all.

I need a function that will return a column from random row from a table. I don't want to use ORDER BY RAND() method to do that, rather i would do this like this:

```
DECLARE MAX_COUNT INT DEFAULT 120000;
DECLARE rand_offset INT;
DECLARE str_rnd_word VARCHAR(255);
SET rand_offset = FLOOR((RAND() * MAX_COUNT));

SELECT word INTO str_rnd_word FROM all_words LIMIT 1 OFFSET rand_offset ;

RETURN str_rnd_word;
```

MySQL throws an error upon creating function with body like that. But when I use hard-coded number as OFFSET it works just fine.

Can someone shed some light on the subject please.

I'm running MySQL 5.0.45 on windows box.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why "I don't want to use ORDER BY RAND() method to do that" ?

Comment: Because the ORDER BY RAND() method is terrible for performance.  Note that he has 120,000 rows in his table.

Comment: well, you can do select like this: 
    SELECT word FROM all_words ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
and what you'll get is a random word from all_words table. This could work for me, but it's VERY slow on large tables. I need to deal with a table with 120000 rows. BTW this number is fixed and won't change.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In MySQL before 5.5, you can't put a variable into the `LIMIT` clause in MySQL stored procedures.  You have to interpolate it into a string and then execute the string as a dynamic query.

```
SET rand_offset = FLOOR(RAND() * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM all_words));
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT word INTO str_rnd_word FROM all_words LIMIT 1 OFFSET ', rand_offset);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Comment: As of MySQL 5.5.6, one *can* use variable `LIMIT` in SP. See [Bug 11918](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918).