# i can not make aritmetic operation inside stored procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

there is an in parameter as page. all i want to do is expel 1 from it and multiply by 10. but it gives me an error every time.

```
IF !a THEN

  SELECT * 
  from entry 
  WHERE topic_foreign_id = ( 
    select topic_id 
    from topic 
    where topic_name = topicName
  )
  ORDER BY entry_time ASC 
  LIMIT 10 OFFSET page;

ELSE

  SELECT * 
  from entry
  WHERE topic_foreign_id = ( 
    select topic_id 
    from topic 
    where topic_name = topicName
  )
  ORDER BY entry_time ASC;

END IF
```

this lines of code works great but when i want to make an aritmetic operation in first SQL query myAdmin throws an error everytime.

```
SELECT * 
from entry 
WHERE topic_foreign_id = ( 
  select topic_id 
  from topic 
  where topic_name = topicName
) 
ORDER BY entry_time ASC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10 * ( page - 1); //throws error
```

Comment: You have forgotten to tell us what the error actually is.

Comment: @AlexK. look end of second code line: 10 * ( page - 1) is the cause of error.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300697/using-variables-as-offset-in-select-statments-inside-mysqls-stored-functions

Answer (score 0):

--- EDITED ---

`LIMIT` doesn't seem to like calculations. Try using a variable and use that value in your stored procedure

```
DECLARE v_page_offset INT DEFAULT 0;
SET v_page_offset = 10*(page-1);
```

Then later

```
LIMIT 10 OFFSET v_page_offset;
```