# Sort a column and select the middle value of the sorted column in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with a number column, now i want to select the middle value from the column after sorting.

demo table

```
index   lat_n      city
  1    223.0000   hyderabad
  2    153.7890   chennai
  3    257.8900   mumbai
```

now my out put should be

`223.0000`

if possible i would like to know how to do this in mysql too.

Comment: Could you please explain in details. `ROWNUM` is the  value generated in the order you select the records. Filtering the values using `ROWNUM` from the value in another table is not relevant

Comment: i am trying to get index of middle value of sorted column , so that i get the proper output, i am new to sql, my query might be wrong, i will edit my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the middle value using `median`

```
with rws as (
  select 153.789 l from dual union all
  select 223 l from dual union all
  select 257.89 l from dual 
)
  select median ( l ) from rws;
  
MEDIAN(L)   
         223
```

If you have an even number of rows, this will return the value that's halfway between the two middle values

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful with `rownum`, as you have to order the results before you try to evaluate that, and you can't use it to compare with equality except for  `= 1`. [You may find this interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30321788/266304).

You could use analytic functions to get the row number and overall row count:

```
select lat_n, city, row_number() over (order by lat_n) as rn, count(*) over () as cnt
from station
```

and then use that in a subquery (inline view or CTE) to filter:

```
select lat_n, city
from (
  select lat_n, city, row_number() over (order by lat_n) as rn, count(*) over () as cnt
  from station
)
where rn = ceil(cnt/2)
```

You've said the column is a number, but with the trailing zeros it looks like you might be storing it as a string; in which case you may need to convert to a number before ordering.

Comment: thank you for you answer , i now understood how to use the row number , but i took that answer as a built function is available.

Comment: As long as you won't ever have an even number of rows - if that's true then I agree *8-) Or maybe you do want to interpolate if that happens. That wasn't clear from your question though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the middle from sql and store it in a middle value like [this](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-basics/mysql-select-into-variable/);
2. Use this middle value in your sql like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300697/using-variables-as-offset-in-select-statments-inside-mysqls-stored-functions);

**Caution**, this code only works to find the middle value if row number is an odd number, you may adjustify it if the row number is an even number;

```sql
select TRUNCATE((select count(*) from cities) / 2, 0) INTO @middle;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT lat_n FROM cities order by lat_n LIMIT 1 OFFSET ',  @middle);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

I tested on a table with 2 million rows. I takes 1 seconds to get the row if there were index on the column and more 5 seconds to get the row if there were no index on the column.

I'm not sure where the index works or not. I guess if there is and index on column lat_n, the speed will be super fast. Because the database server will not have to scan all the lat_n value of each row.